# MEAN-How to find the length of an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

This is my mongoose Schema

```
let ItemSchema = new Schema({

    productId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Product",
    },
    quantity: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: [1, 'Quantity can not be less then 1.']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    total: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    }
}, {

})

const CartSchema = new Schema({
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
    },
   items:   [ItemSchema],
  subTotal: {
        default: 0,
        type: Number
    }
}, {
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('cart', CartSchema);
```

what would be the best method to find the length of **items** array
I only just want the length of items array

Suggest me a function to get the length

this is what I am trying to do

```
 exports.arrlen = function (req, res){
     var len = cart.items.length
     console.log(len)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing the small mistake that firstly I need to get all then only I can find the length of it through web API

this is my API file

```
exports.arrlen = async function (){
    try{
   //made changes here\\
  let cart = await cartRepository.cart();
            let len = cart.items.length
            console.log(len)
     }
catch  (err){
    console.log(err)

}
}
```

this is my cart repository file

```
exports.cart = async () => {
    const carts = await Cart.find().populate({
        path: "items.productId",
        select: " name imageName category colour size discription price total"
    });;
    return carts[0];
};
```

Comment: Which one do you want,
A: Count document in collection.
B: Count array field size in one document.

Comment: I just want to use it in a for loop

Answer (score 2):

Use `aggregate` and `$size` in `$project` is what you need.

Test data :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "items": [1,2]
}
```

Aggregate :

```
cart.aggregate([
    {  
        $project: {sizeOfItems:{$size:"$items"} }
    }
])
```

Result :

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "sizeOfItems" : 2
}
```

Comment: can you please explain in detail

Comment: [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)、[size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/)、[project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)


`aggregate` Process data records and return computed results.
`$size` Counts and returns the total number of items in an array.
`$project` Passes along the documents with the requested fields to the next stage in the pipeline.

Comment: cant we can find the length with the method I am trying to do

Comment: `find` is used to query exist data, you need to project a new field which value is size of another array field.

Comment: basically I want to run a for loop for the number of items in an array ,for that I need to find the length of array first . Can you suggest me some ways to perform a loop. If you made me explain it would be thank full. also I want to perform it with web API in node js

Comment: Actually, my answer in the beginning is already what `find the length of array first`

Comment: you can see my answer what I was demanding